# Brown Rice vs White Rice in Stuffed Pepper

Tags: rice, slow-cooking, crockpot

I often make a stuffed pepper in my crock pot stuffed with a ground meat and rice mixture. For liquid, I pour some tomato juice into the pepper. I used to make it with white rice, and it worked perfectly every time.

I recently switched to using brown rice, but it keeps coming out cruchy with the rice almost completely raw. I tried adding more liquid this time, but it didn't help.

I'm not sure what else to try and am ready to go back to using white rice. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brown rice takes considerably longer to cook than white rice, and requires a higher ratio of liquid to rice.

It may be somewhat helpful to pre-soak the brown rice, but that may not completely compensate for the longer cooking time.

The main issue is going to be getting the rice fully hydrated and cooked through without badly overcooking the peppers.

Your best bet is probably to start with cooked brown rice, which my survey having googled "brown rice stuffed pepper recipe" indicates is the most common method, although they don't generally employ a crock pot.

For a one-step fully crock-pot based recipe, white rice may be indicated.

Comment: Thanks. That's what my husband suggested. I was hoping to do it in one step, but it sounds like it's not really possible.